# How to solve Unchecked cast in android without suppressing the warning

Tags: android, loader, unchecked-cast

How do I solve this issue without using SuppressWarning("uncheckedcast"), this there any way to check the object before casting it or any other way to solve this issue. 
The problem is inside onLoadFinished(). I am using the data for different datatypes as you can see, first as boolean and then List.
Thank you in advance.

```
 package com.howaboutthis.satyaraj.wallpaper;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;    
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


public class FragmentChanging extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks  {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public FragmentChanging(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup
    container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = 
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_changing_wallpaper, container, false);

     getLoaderMangaer.init(0,null,FragmentChanging.this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (id == 0 || id == 2){
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Settings...");
            dialog.show();
              }
            return new TestInternetLoader(getContext());           
              }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {
        int id = loader.getId();

        if (id == 0 || id == 2){
            boolean check = (Boolean) data;
            if (check) 
                if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
        }
        else if(id == 3)
            List<Bitmap> bitmaps = (List<Bitmap>) data;  //Unchecked cast

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {

    }

}
```

Comment: `if (data instanceof List<Bitmap>)`

Comment: please show how you declare the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

Comment: Error, it says Illegal generic type for instanceof @KostasDrak

Comment: i used implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks  @0X0nosugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the lint warning by using a `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Bitmap>>` . If you want to do so, you'll have to change (almost) every occurrence of `Loader` to `Loader<List<Bitmap>>`.
(An exception seems to be `onLoaderReset(Loader loader)`)

Moreover, if you use a custom `AsyncTaskLoader` it would have to extend  `AsyncTaskLoader<List<Bitmap>>`.

Then you can write

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Bitmap>> loader, List<Bitmap> data) {

    List<Bitmap> bitmaps = data;
}
```

**EDIT**

If the suggested approach is not possible because the type of data may vary you can check for the types you are going to handle like this:

```
if (data instanceof List<?>){
    List temp = (List)data;
    // do what's required for List data
    // (if necessary do a type check on list elements)
    if (tempList.size() > 0){
        Object firstItem = tempList.get(0);
        if (firstItem instanceof Bitmap){
            // now you know that your Loader gave you a List with at least one Bitmap
            List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object item: tempList){
                if (item instanceof Bitmap){
                    bitmaps.add((Bitmap) item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else if (data instanceof Boolean){
   boolean check = (Boolean) data;
        if (check){ 
            // handle Boolean data   
        } 
}
```

Comment: The thing is, i will be calling the loader multiple times and the data will have different datatypes so i can't use generic datatypes @0x0nosugar

Comment: I have edited the code so you can understand why i can't use LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Bitmap>> @0x0nosugar

Comment: Nope, didn't work. It still shows Unchecked cast. @0x0nosugar

Comment: @Satyarai Moily - no "unchecked cast" if you're also checking the individual List items before adding them to the List of Bitmap. I'm afraid if we want to write less code we'll have to use "Suppress" or start using Kotlin instead of Java.

Comment: i have like 8 different conditions not just bitmap and Boolean.

Comment: @Satyaraj Moily - I'm sure you're able to handle them now that I've shown you how to do it :-) Personally I'd suppress the Lint warning and put all of the casting into a try-catch block. If the ClassCastException fires then I'd throw an IllegalArgumentException with a message like  "Object must be one of the following...". I think this approach is ok because it is meant to enforce a contract of your app with your AsyncTaskLoader.